# call code behind method from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a code behind method

```
protected void RadTreeView1_NodeClick(object sender,Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
}
```

I need to call this  This `RadTreeView1_NodeClick` method from Pageload in javascript
What would I do? Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

C# methods can be called from Javascript, but have to be PageMethods. A PageMethod, is defined just like any method in your code-behind. The only requirement is that, you should add [WebMethod] attribute before method's signature. Then, your C# method can be called with PageMethod object from Javascript. Please note that EnablePageMethod property of the ScriptManager on your page should be set to true.

For more info visit see this example: http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx

Regarding your RadTreeview, I believe that it has client API, and you should be able to do whatever you want using it. Please see RadTreeview client examples and look at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess triggering the click would be easiest. So I would do something like (using jQuery):

$("#RadTreeView1").click();
or $("#RadTreeView1").trigger('click');

You should replace RadTreeView1 with the ClientID of the button though.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript:

```
__doPostBack("radtree","args");
```

You can call on document ready, if you use jquery:

```
$(function(){
   __doPostBack("radtree","args");
});
```

Or use body onload, and create a function which executes the __doPostBack.

C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request["__EVENTTARGET"]=="radtree")
    {   
       var arguments = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; // this will be "args"
       RadTreeView1_NodeClick(pass parameters);           
    }
}
protected void RadTreeView1_NodeClick(object sender,Telerik.Web.UI.RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
}
```